# Фигуры в  C#

Tags: c#

Только начинаю работать с фигурами в C#. Вот небольшая программа, которая рисует линию, и при нажатии кнопки должна нарисовать овал. Но почему-то не рисует.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Блок_схема
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black, 5), 100, 100, 20, 50);   
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1),new Point(200, 200),new Point(200, 300));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вынести ``Graphics g`` в глобальные переменные

    Graphics g;
    public Form1()
    {
    ...

если не поможет, напишу более достоверный способ.

Comment: NullReferensException вот такая ошибка. Если можно, то другой способ.

Comment: я так и думал=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не самый удачный, плохо расширяемый, но рабочий вариант:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool flag;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          flag = true;
          Refresh();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);    
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;    
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1),new Point(200, 200),new Point(200, 300));    
        if(flag)      
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black, 5), 100, 100, 20, 50);         
    }    
}
```

Refresh() вызывает событие OnPaint(), которое перересовывает всю форму, на вашем месте я бы все фигуры, которые могут быть нарисованы, инкапсулировал в отдельный класс, а уже в OnPaint`e прорисовывал объект этого класса в зависимости от их наличия, т.е. у вас должен быть класс, описывающий Блок-Схему и логику работы с ней - получить/добавть/удалить/обновить элементы блок-схемы и т.п. и т.д, а любые изменения объекта сопровождались бы Refresh'ем.

Comment: Спасибо, буду работать.